# react/react-leaflet not immediately loading information

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, react-leaflet

[Example of issue](https://streamable.com/hsn8wb)

```
import firebase from 'firebase/app';
import { MapContainer, TileLayer, Marker, Popup } from 'react-leaflet';
import { OpenStreetMapProvider } from 'leaflet-geosearch'
import SearchControl from "./SearchControl";

const userId = sessionStorage.getItem('uid')
const fullNames = []
const provider = new OpenStreetMapProvider()
var vendors = []

const VendorMap = (props) => {
    firebase.firestore().collection("vendors")
        .where('belongsTo', '==', userId)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if(fullNames.includes(doc.data().fullName) == false) {
                    fullNames.push(doc.data().fullName)
                    provider.search({query: doc.data().address}).then(function (result) {
                        vendors.push([doc.data(), [result[0].y, result[0].x]])
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log("Error getting collection: ", error)
                    })
                }
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting collection: ", error)
        })

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={3} scrollWheelZoom={true}>
            <TileLayer
            attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <SearchControl provider={provider} showMarker={true} showPopup={true} popupFormat={({ query, result }) => result.label} maxMarkers={3} retainZoomLevel={false} animateZoom={true} autoClose={false} searchLabel={"Address to search for..."} keepResult={true} />
            {vendors.map((vendor) => 
                <Marker key={vendor[0].fullName} position={[vendor[1][0], vendor[1][1]]}>
                    <Popup>
                        <span>{vendor[0].fullName}</span>
                    </Popup>
                </Marker>
            )}
        </MapContainer>
    )
}

export default VendorMap
```

The above link is a video of my issue (its only 10 seconds). React is not immediately loading all of the map markers every time it loads. Sometimes all of the markers load, sometimes only 1 does and I have to click on the navigation bar link for the rest to load.

I am not understanding what the issue could be since I am adding all of the markers one after another to the map. React also doesn't seem to be loading the information from firestore correctly as when I log into the website, I have to completely refresh the website before information begins to load.

If anyone has any insight into what I may be doing wrong and how to fix this, it would be great! I am really new to NodeJS and ReactJS so excuse any common issues on my end.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen I put the actual code and removed the photo of it. I just don't know how to describe the issue well enough without showing what the issue is. It seems like a weird problem that I'm not sure if many others have.

Answer (score 0):

I am not able to reproduce your issue but the first two things you need to change is:

1. Place the async operation inside a `useEffect` hook to load only once when the page loads.
2. use a `useState` hook to store the data received from the async operation **inside** VendorMap component  because storing the data in a variable outside the functional component like you do might have unexpected results as React does not know when to update the DOM and compare the old with the new values.

As a result create a local variable using a useState hook

```
const [vendors, setVendors] = useState([]);

useEffect(() => {
   firebase.firestore().collection("vendors")
        .where('belongsTo', '==', userId)
        .get()
        .then(querySnapshot => {
            querySnapshot.forEach((doc) => {
                if(fullNames.includes(doc.data().fullName) == false) {
                    fullNames.push(doc.data().fullName)
                    provider.search({query: doc.data().address}).then(function (result) {               
                       setVendords(yourVariable) // update the vendors array
                    }).catch((error) => {
                        console.log("Error getting collection: ", error)
                    })
                }
            })
        }).catch((error) => {
            console.log("Error getting collection: ", error)
        })
}, []);
```

Inside `setVendors` update vendors variable. I am not sure regarding the data you receive that is the reason I did not put the exact value

3. If you update `fullNames` like `vendors` follow the same pattern as for `vendors` variable.